# Opening Words of the Shemona Esrei in Mussaf and Mincha

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

At the beginning of the Shemona Esrei for both Shacharit and Maariv, one recites the words "אדני שפתי תפתח ופי יגיד תהלתיך". At the beginning of the Shemona Esrei for both Mussaf and Mincha, however, one precedes those words with, "כי שם ה' אקרא הבו גודל לאלקינו".

Why is it specifically by Mussaf and Mincha that those words are added?

Comment: Note that that addition is not universal...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22502

Comment: There is no difference between Shacharit and Mincha in this regard for the leader's repetition